# Referring a table in a text does not follow individual number, but obeys the figures' numbers

Tags: tables

By help of @Leandris we could have a table by below command. However, there is a major problem: when I use \labe{tab:table} for referring this table in tex, the number of the table is the next number of our figures. For example we have three plots and one table. When we say: `The table~\ref{tab:table} represents....`, we see in output :`The table 4 represents...`. But we have just one table and three plots!!! how overcome this problem?!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\cellg}{\cellcolor{LightGreen}}
\newcommand{\cellb}{\cellcolor{LightBlue}}
\newcommand{\cellr}{\cellcolor{LightPink}}

\begin{document}


\[
\begin{array}{ l *{9}{c} }
\toprule
m & \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^*(m)}     & t^*(m)
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^{**}(m)}  & t^{**}(m)
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^{***}(m)} & t^{***}(m) \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
& 1-1/m & 1+1/m & m\pi
& 1-3/m & 1+3/m & m\pi
& 1-5/m & 1+5/m & m\pi \\
\midrule
\cellg 1 & \cellg 0   & \cellg 2   &  \cellg \pi \\
2 & 1/2 & 3/2 & 2\pi \\
\cellg 3 & \cellg 2/3 & \cellg 4/3 & \cellg 3\pi & \cellb 0   & \cellb 2   & \cellb 3\pi \\
4 & 3/4 & 5/4 & 4\pi & 1/4 & 7/4 & 4\pi \\
\cellg 5 & \cellg 4/5 & \cellg 6/5 & \cellg 5\pi & \cellb 2/5 & \cellb 8/5 & \cellb 5\pi & \cellr 0 & \cellr 2 & \cellr 5\pi \\
6 & 5/6 & 7/6 & 6\pi & 3/6 & 9/6 & 6\pi & 1/6 & 11/6 & 6\pi \\
\cellg 7 & \cellg 6/7 & \cellg 8/7 & \cellg 7\pi & \cellb 4/7 & \cellb 10/7 & \cellb 7\pi & \cellr 2/7 & \cellr 12/7 & \cellr 7\pi \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\label{tab:table}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example currently does not contain any labels or references. Please edit the example to make the issue reproducible.

Comment: I corrected it. Thankx so much

Comment: Now it contains a label, but still no reference (`\ref{tab:table}`) and no caption to show the number, and also no documentclass, so the issue is not really reproducible yet. However, it can probably be done by putting `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` around the array, and `\caption` and `\label` before `\end{table}`. For LaTeX it does not matter what is inside of a `table` environment, normally it is a `tabular` or a `tabularx` environment, but it can also be a figure, or an array, or a line of text. In any case, a `Table X` caption will be generated with the table counter.

Comment: What exactly are you expacting `\ref{tab:table}` to represent here? There is no obvious number to it to refer to. As Marijn says, you should probably use a table + caption around the entire construction. Remember the label needs to come after the caption (as it is what gives the number not the env)

Comment: If your table has no caption informing the reader that this table is "Table 1:..." how should a reference like "See table 1" help the reader know what you are referring to? Therefore, place the whole array into a `table` environment and add a caption.

Comment: the marjin's comment also was so good

Comment: Thankx of all for their comments. All of them are very helpful. Thnkxxx

Comment: You are embedding your array/table in `\[ ... \]`.  While this centers its contents, it explicitly is not numbered.  If you want a number in the form of an equation number (vertically centered and placed to the right or left, depending on your document class and options), you can wrap it instead in `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`.